# Handle radio buttons selection with onChange event

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, state, onchange

I have the following code:

```
let checkId = -1;

const checkChange= e => {
    checkId = e.target.id;
}

{ data.map(param=> (
    <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
        // paramd is an integer 1, 2, 3... etc. so is storing the desired value properly.
        <input className="form-check-input" type={'radio'} name={'radio' + param.Id} id={param.Id} value={data.Name} onChange={checkChange} checked={checkId == param.Id ? true : false} />
        <label className="form-check-label" for={param.Id}>{param.Name}</label>
    </div>
))}
```

What I want to do is to handle the checked attribute and keeping only one input selected so when I check other the previous loose the checked and set the clicked as checked.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that you use the same `name` for all the inputs. Additionally in the `onChange` handler, you must use `e.target.value` while setting the new value.

```
const [checkId, setCheckId] = useState(-1)


const checkChange = e => {
    setCheckId(e.target.value)
}

{ data.map((param, paramIdx)=> (
    <div key={paramIdx} className='form-check form-check-inline'>
        <input className='form-check-input' type='radio' name='for-something' id={param.Id} value={param.Name} onChange={checkChange} checked={checkId === param.Id} />
        <label className='form-check-label' for={param.Id}>{param.Name}</label>
    </div>
))}
```

#### Reference

1. [Radio Button](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)

Comment: I renamed my radio button to have the same name but this doesn't solve my issue. The radio is not getting checked.

Comment: Then the problem is in the way you are setting the data. Could you share the complete code snippet of the file please. Can you also share what the data object looks like? I have updated my answer with a different way of updating the `checkId`. Please take a look. I would recommend the use of a react hook called as `useState` as well. Although not necessary but recommended.

Comment: Yes. React uses state management in order to maintain updates to the DOM properly. Perhaps a further read of the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) would help.

Comment: Hmmm... very funny and weird like a hell solution. I just removed all the cheked attribute from my input and now works like a charm. There is nothing else to do to handle the unselect thing that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution of my problem. I was setting and reading my values properly. The problem was setting the checked=true/false attribute. I changed this:

```
<input className="form-check-input" type={'radio'} name={'radio' + param.Id} id={param.Id} value={data.Name} onChange={checkChange} checked={checkId == param.Id ? true : false} />
```

to

```
<input className="form-check-input" type={'radio'} name={'radio' + param.Id} id={param.Id} value={data.Name} onChange={checkChange} />
```

This handles the select/unselect cheked as I wanted. If anyone could share more details about why checked=condition returning true/false would be great.